# How to read and show file from back in python

Tags: python, back, readfile

In python I want to show short term of string when I read from file and I want its show from back to fronts

Example. I read this string from file "I want to show some text from back"

I want to show like this "...some text from back"

How can I get string like this ? Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

To get the last 4 words

```
>>> S = "I want to show some text from back"
>>> '...'+' '.join(S.split()[-4:])
'...some text from back'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
' '.join("I want to show some text from back".split()[-4:])
```

The magic is the `[-4:]` slice. That says to take list elements starting from the 4th to last. Nothing after the colon means continue until the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the string, indexing backwards from the end.

```
s = "I want to show some text from back"
print "...%s" % (s[-20:])
>>... some text from back
```